# Android application swap between activitys stops

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Hei guys. I am new to Android programming. I am trying to make an app that controls a rc car (Arduino). In this app are the next activities:

1. Button Commands
2. Tilt Command
3. Vocal Command
4. Instructions
5. About

When I open the app it suddenly stops and I don't know why. Can someone help me by looking at the code and tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks a lot.

```
Button buttonCommand;
Button tiltCommand;
Button vocalCommand;
Button instructions;
Button about;
Button arduino; // Links Button
Button android; // Links Button

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

    buttonCommand = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttons);
    tiltCommand = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tilt);
    vocalCommand = (Button)findViewById(R.id.vocal);
    instructions = (Button)findViewById(R.id.instructions);
    about = (Button)findViewById(R.id.about);
    arduino = (Button)findViewById(R.id.arduino);
    android = (Button)findViewById(R.id.android);
}

public void onClickButton(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ButtonCommand.class); // ButtonCommand Activity
    startActivity(i);
}

public void onClickTilt(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TiltCommand.class); // TiltCommand Activity
    startActivity(i);
}

public void onClickVocal(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),VocalCommand.class); // VocalCommand Activity
    startActivity(i);
}

public void onClickInstructions(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Instructions.class); // Instructions Activity
    startActivity(i);
}

public void onClickAbout(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),About.class); // About Activity
    startActivity(i);
}

public void onClickArduino(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://forum.arduino.cc/"));
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void onClickAndroid(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://forum.xda-developers.com/"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Buna George, is very important to add the message displayed in LogCat

Comment: Hey. I know. My pc is running a bit slow and I am using the traditional debugging mode. Code the app, make the apk and installing on my phone. Sorry for not be able to provide the LogCat message.

Comment: You can run LogCat on phones as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your app stops at the start, probably you are missing to add the registry of your activities into your `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
   <activity android:name=".ButtonCommand" />
   <activity android:name=".TiltCommand" />
   <activity android:name=".VocalCommand" />
   <activity android:name=".Instructions" />
   <activity android:name=".About" />
```

George, you need to create an OnClickListener for each button for example:

```
buttonCommand = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttons);
buttonCommand.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                      Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ButtonCommand.class); // ButtonCommand Activity
                      startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
```

Plus: and the internet permission to open urls:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: George see into the LogCat inside the Android Monitor, what error message is displayed!

Comment: I will try now by creating an OnClickListener for each button. Come back soon with updates. Thanks.